# Dealing with NA and boolean sums in R

Tags: r, dplyr, boolean, na

I'm trying to create a new variable that involves the sum of products of a numeric value and a logical (indicator), but the final result does not make sense.

**DATA**

I've generated the following dataset as a minimum reproducible example for the issue I'm having. Each row is an individual and the columns `mJSW_BL`, `mJSW_12`, `mJSW_24`, and `mJSW_36` are the measurements at baseline, 12, 24 and 36. The last variable I'm creating, `JSNCASE_TP` indicates the first time (12, 24 or 36) for which an individual meets the definition of of case (decrease from baseline by 0.7). The calculation of `JSNCASE_TP` should ignore NA values and can take on the values 0,12,24, or 36.

```
require(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
N = 10
mJSW_BL <- runif(N,0.1,2)
mJSW_12 <- runif(N,0.1,2)
mJSW_24 <- runif(N,0.1,2)
mJSW_36 <- runif(N,0.1,2)

#Randomly set some values to NA
mJSW_12[sample(N,2)] <- NA
mJSW_36[sample(N,1)] <- NA

#Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(mJSW_BL,mJSW_12,mJSW_24,mJSW_36)

df2 <- df %>%
       #Create variables indicating decrease from BL
       mutate(mJSW_BLto12 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_12,
              mJSW_BLto24 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_24,
              mJSW_BLto36 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_36) %>%
       #JSN case - decrease by 0.7 from BL
       mutate(JSNCASE_12 = (mJSW_BLto12>=0.7),
              JSNCASE_24 = (mJSW_BLto24>=0.7),
              JSNCASE_36 = (mJSW_BLto36>=0.7)) %>%
       #Which timepoint did JSN first occur?
       mutate(JSNCASE_TP = sum(12*JSNCASE_12, 
                               24*(JSNCASE_24 & !JSNCASE_12),
                               36*(JSNCASE_36 & !(JSNCASE_12 | JSNCASE_24)),
                               na.rm=TRUE))
```

**ISSUES**

In data `df2`, take for example, row 4, where `JSNCASE_12`, `JSNCASE_24`, and `JSNCASE_36` are all `TRUE`, but `JSNCASE_TP=36` . It should be `JSNCASE_TP=12`. Additionally, take row 6, where `JSNCASE_12=NA`, `JSNCASE_24=TRUE`, and `JSNCASE_36=FALSE`. I should get `JSNCASE_TP=24`. Maybe I'm missing something basic, but I've tried several ways and haven't produced the desired result. The values of `JSNCASE_TP` for the 10 rows should be `0,0,0,12,0,24,24,0,0,0`.

**EDIT** 
Thanks to @Dave2e's comments, the code below works:

```
df2 <- df %>%
   #Create variables indicating decrease from BL
   mutate(mJSW_BLto12 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_12,
          mJSW_BLto24 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_24,
          mJSW_BLto36 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_36) %>%
   #JSN case - decrease by 0.7 from BL
   mutate(JSNCASE_12 = (mJSW_BLto12>=0.7),
          JSNCASE_24 = (mJSW_BLto24>=0.7),
          JSNCASE_36 = (mJSW_BLto36>=0.7)) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   #Which timepoint did JSN first occur?
   mutate(JSNCASE_TP = sum(12*JSNCASE_12, 
                           24*(JSNCASE_24 & (!JSNCASE_12| is.na(JSNCASE_12))),
                           36*(JSNCASE_36 & ((!JSNCASE_12 | is.na(JSNCASE_12)) & 
                                             (!JSNCASE_24 | is.na(JSNCASE_24)))),
                           na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Your use of `sum` is incorrect. The function is combining all three vectors and returning a single grand total.  You'll need to perform the summation row wise.

Comment: Thanks. This gets close once I add "rowwise() %>%" before the last `mutate`. However, I still can't get the first "24" (row 6) for `JSNCASE_TP` because the sum evaluates to `(FALSE & !(NA | TRUE))`, which outputs 0.

Comment: This may work for the other case: `24*(df2$JSNCASE_24 & (!JSNCASE_12| is.na(JSNCASE_12)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the the NA mixed with the TRUE/FALSE does complicates things.

Here is a hack using the `apply` function. Basically finds the first column with TRUE in it then multiples by 12 to get the proper time.  Since it is possible all columns are FALSE, it needs to check and handle cases where inf values are returned by the `min` function.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  #Create variables indicating decrease from BL
  mutate(mJSW_BLto12 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_12,
         mJSW_BLto24 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_24,
         mJSW_BLto36 = mJSW_BL - mJSW_36) %>%
  #JSN case - decrease by 0.7 from BL
  mutate(JSNCASE_12 = (mJSW_BLto12>=0.7),
         JSNCASE_24 = (mJSW_BLto24>=0.7),
         JSNCASE_36 = (mJSW_BLto36>=0.7))


df2$JSNCASE_TP<-12*apply(df2[,8:10], 1, function(x){ ifelse(is.infinite(min(which(x==TRUE))), 0, min(which(x==TRUE)) )})
```

I'm sure there is a possible dplyr version of this.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` and `apply` to get the column name if it exists otherwise 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('.*_\\d+')), list(ind=~mJSW_BL-.>=0.7)) %>% 
  mutate(JSNCASE_TP = apply(.[grepl('.*_ind',names(.))], 1, function(x){
                             x <- x[!is.na(x)]
                             ifelse(all(!x), 0, names(x)[which.max(x)])
}))

     mJSW_BL   mJSW_12   mJSW_24   mJSW_36 mJSW_12_ind mJSW_24_ind mJSW_36_ind  JSNCASE_TP
1  0.6044665 0.4913517 1.8759399 1.0159522       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE           0
2  0.8070354 0.4354578 0.5030708 1.2391751       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE           0
3  1.1884214 1.4053434 1.3381802 1.0377285       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE           0
4  1.8255948 0.8297971 0.3385547 0.4538134        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE mJSW_12_ind
5  0.4831957 1.5626987 0.6077193 1.6720093       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE           0
6  1.8069404        NA 0.8336168 1.3700868          NA        TRUE       FALSE mJSW_24_ind
7  1.8948830 1.4634752 0.1254416 1.6090557       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE mJSW_24_ind
8  1.3555158 1.9846216 0.8265371        NA       FALSE       FALSE          NA           0
9  1.2953167        NA 1.7524126 1.4750508          NA       FALSE       FALSE           0
10 0.2173939 1.5771459 0.7466631 0.8814214       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE           0
```

However, it's better to transfer your data into [tidy data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), do the analysis then transfer back into wide format. Here is one way

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% rownames_to_column(var = 'id') %>% 
  gather(key,value,-id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Ind = ifelse(is.na(value), FALSE, (first(value)-value)>=0.7), JSNCASE_TP = ifelse(any(Ind),key[Ind],'0')) %>% 
  select(-Ind) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(id))
```